# xcode 9 source control does not show git repo

Tags: xcode

I am getting a problem in Xcode 9.1. where my source control does not show git repository.

[image]

Comment: You can get it on source control navigator

Comment: yes its on  source control navigator and also source control menu all option is disable.

Comment: Try git command line commands to test if your repo is ok. "git status" is good for start